# how to use 'GROUP BY' function with below query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

In the below code I want to apply group function only on three columns as given in group by condition. But it is giving error, wrong number of arguments.

```
select a.id,a.name,  
       c.code,
       a.active_dt,
       a.inactive_dt,
       b.category,
       count(a.id,a.name,c.code) count
from student a,class b, descrip c
where a.id=b.id
and a.id=c.id
group by a.id,a.name,c.code
    having count(a.id,a.name,c.code) >1;
```

Comment: This code contains many errors. Add what you want to do, also example data and expected output

Comment: `count(a.id,a.name,c.code)` that's a strange looking query

Comment: What should `count(a.id,a.name,c.code)` do? Do you need to count all the rows, or maybe only the rows where at least one of `a.id,a.name,c.code` is not null?

Comment: @Aleksej i just want the data grouped on the basis of 3 coloumns i.e.a.id,a.name,c.code

Comment: So, why not `count(*)`?

Comment: @Aleksej as in order to use group by i need to select as many coloumns as in group by condition.

'select a.id,a.name,  
       c.code,
       a.active_dt,
       a.inactive_dt,
       b.category,
       count(*)  count
from student a,class b, descrip c
where a.id=b.id
and a.id=c.id
group by a.id,a.name,c.code,a.active_dt,a.inactive_dt,b.category
having count(*) >1;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.name,
        c.code,
        a.active_dt,
        a.inactive_dt,
        b.category,
        COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.name, c.code) AS CNT
    FROM
        student a,
        class b,
        descrip c
    WHERE
        a.id=b.id AND
        a.id=c.id
)
WHERE CNT > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you simply need this:

```
select a.id,a.name,  
       c.code,
       a.active_dt,
       a.inactive_dt,
       b.category,
       count(*) count
from student a,class b, descrip c
where a.id=b.id
and a.id=c.id
group by a.id,a.name,c.code
    having count(*) >1;
```

A small example of how `count()` ad `group by` work:

```
create table testGroup(a, b, c) as ( 
select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
select 5, 6, 7 from dual union all
select 5, 6, 7 from dual union all
select 5, 6, 9 from dual union all
select 1, 2, 9 from dual 
)
```

The number of columns you need to use in your group does not affect the way you use the count; say you need to group by 3 columns:

```
SQL> select a, b, c, count(*)
  2  from testGroup
  3  group by a, b, c
  4  having count(*) > 1;

         A          B          C   COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         5          6          7          2
         1          2          3          2
```

And if you only need to aggregate by 2 columns:

```
SQL> select a, b, count(*)
  2  from testGroup
  3  group by a, b
  4  having count(*) > 1;

         A          B   COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- ----------
         5          6          3
         1          2          3
```

This assumes that you need to count the rows, no matter if the values are null or not.

Comment: yes you are right but in your last table as you mentioned i want to select a, b, c i.e. all coloumns.

Comment: I can't get the point. With the table of my example, what should the result be?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, c.code, a.active_dt, a.inactive_dt, b.category, 
       count(DISTINCT a.id,a.name,c.code) [count]
FROM student a
INNER JOIN class b
    ON a.id=b.id
INNER JOIN descrip c
    ON a.id=c.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, c.code, a.active_dt, a.inactive_dt, b.category
HAVING count(a.id,a.name,c.code) > 1
```

Comment: Not really sure about Oracle. But it will work in sql! @Aleksej

Comment: Even if this works in some DBMS, this will not work in Oracle, and the question is for Oracle.